# Define URL to jump to a specific page element, height or anchor after ajax call

Tags: ajax, facebook, hash, anchor, facebook-like

I have a website running on wordpress and ajax. 
All the content ist loaded via ajax with deeplinking and hashHistory.

URLs look like this:

```
http://www.website.com/#/lang/page/
```

On one of the pages i want to implement multiple facebook like buttons to boost some of the contents popularity .

To make this happen i need to specify different urls for different page elements to define different href tags for each XFBML Like Button.

My first thought was to create anchors on the page and to create Urls like `http://www.website.com/#/lang/page#anchor`. Of course that doesnt work as the second hashtag messes up with hashHistory and the ajax call.

So, i want to define a URL to jump to a specific page element, height or anchor after the ajax call.

Is there any way of doing this? Or am i missing a very simple solution on this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you can use [ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

Comment: but that doesnt influence the url. how could i jump to a part of my page with ScrollTo on page load? i dont think that is possible.